# Are Kyoto Cabinet and Tokyo Cabinet dead?

Tags: tokyo-cabinet, kyotocabinet, tokyo-tyrant

These projects sound interesting, but I don't see any active development, and the code base depends on obsolete sowftware (GLIBC_2.14...)

Or am I looking in the wrong places?

Answer (score 0):

The main author seems to have stopped development. However, there are many active users around (e.g. on the mailing list tokyocabinet-users@googlegroups.com).

Can you specify the dependencies on obsolete software?